# Importing from directory gives ImportError

Tags: python

I have the following directory structure, in Ubuntu:

```
/Test/Foo
/Test/Foo/foo.py
```

If I am in `/Test`, and I run `python` from the command line, followed by `from Foo import foo`, I get the following error: `ImportError: No module named Foo`.

But this is very confusing, since according to [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.path), one of the directories used to search when importing is the directory from which the script was invoked. If I print out `sys.path` though, it does not include `/Test`, it just includes other standard Python directories.

Any idea what is going on?

Comment: its just a random python file and directory, not a module, you're missing an `__init__.py`

Comment: I was following https://realpython.com/absolute-vs-relative-python-imports/, which says that you don't need `__init__.py` to be able to import like this. However, after having a second look, I think that this is only for Python3...

Comment: Try to `cd` into `Foo` try the command again see what the result is perhaps.

Comment: If I `cd` into `Foo`, then run `python`, followed by `import foo`, then this works ok.

Comment: So basically it's a matter of either having `__init__.py` where you want to run the command or script from, or maybe try calling you module like `from Test.Foo import foo`. You can create the init file like this `touch  __init__.py`.

Comment: What version of Python are you using? Implicitly namespaced packages (i.e. no `__init__.py`) only applies to Python3.3+. I'L'l's advise is incorrect unless your're using a very old version of Python

Answer (score 0):

If I'm getting you right, what you are trying to achieve here is the `Foo` to be a package and `foo` be a module.

Since `Foo` is not made into a package (You don't have `__init__.py` in the directory), it is not recognized as a package and thus not imported.

When you move into `/Test/Foo`, then you are simply importing the module `foo`, which will work.

What you possibly need to do here is to create an `__init__.py` file inside `/Test/Foo` and then import the module from the package.

Or you can try relative imports. Something like `from .Foo import foo`.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need a function try this (python 2.7):
sys.path.insert() inserts the directory specified in the path python uses to find files.
commify.py is a file in subdirectory xyz that contains a function commify(value)

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.getcwd() + r'\xyz')
from commify import commify

print commify(12345678)
```

output: 12,345,678